# I'm trying to interpret this IA32 assembly language code

Tags: c, assembly

I have this IA32 assembly language code I'm trying to convert into regular C code.

```
.globl fn
    .type   fn, @function
fn:
    pushl   %ebp #setup
    movl    $1, %eax #setup 1 is in A
    movl    %esp, %ebp #setup
    movl    8(%ebp), %edx # pointer X is in D
    cmpl    $1, %edx # (*x > 1)
    jle     .L4
.L5:
    imull   %edx, %eax
    subl    $1, %edx
    cmpl    $1, %edx
    jne     .L5
.L4:
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

The trouble I'm having is deciding what type of comparison is going on. I don't get how the program gets to the L5 cache. L5 seems to be a loop since there's a comparison within it. I'm also unsure of what is being returned because it seems like most of the work is done is the %edx register, but doesn't go back to %eax for returning.

What I have so far:

```
int fn(int x)
{

}
```

Comment: I'd start by generating Intel format assembly code, so you're at least starting from something halfway readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like it's computing a factorial. Ignoring the stack frame manipulation and such, we're left with:

```
movl    $1, %eax #setup 1 is in A
```

Puts 1 into eax.

```
movl    8(%ebp), %edx # pointer X is in D
```

Retrieves a parameter into edx

```
imull   %edx, %eax
```

Multiplies eax by edx, putting the result into eax.

```
subl    $1, %edx
cmpl    $1, %edx
jne     .L5
```

Decrements edx and repeats if edx != 1.

In other words, this is roughly equivalent to:

```
unsigned fact(unsigned input) { 
    unsigned retval = 1;

    for ( ; input != 1; --input)
        retval *= input;
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: What happened to the `jle` shouldn't there be a `input<` in the loop and `input != 1` be an if statement

Comment: @user3395013: this has a test at the top of the loop, and another at the bottom. You *could* translate that as an `if` with a `do`/`while` inside it, but something like a `for` or `while` loop would be a lot more common. The test at the top is used only to control the first iteration of the loop. The other iterations are controlled by the test at the bottom.